# Blackberry10 cascades onTrigger

Tags: blackberry-cascades

I have used a [TabbedPane](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__tabbedpane.html) in this while clicking i need to call an another qml file here is the code am using but its not working

```
TabbedPane {
  showTabsOnActionBar: tabs
  sidebarState: SidebarState.VisibleCompact
  Tab {
    imageSource: "asset:///msg.png"
    Page {
      id: page1                 
      actions: [
        ActionItem {
          onTriggered: {
            var page = pageDefinition.createObject();
            navigationPane.push(page);
          }
          attachedObjects: ComponentDefinition {
            id: pageDefinition;
            source: "x.qml"
          }
        }
      ]
      actionBarVisibility: ChromeVisibility.Visible
    }
}
```

can anyone send me code how to add Click event inside this function
    Thanks

Comment: I reformatted your code for readability, however there is a stray semi-colon `;` after your `id: pageDefinition` line. (Semi-Colons only appear at the end of the JavaScript statements within the "event handlers" like `onTriggered`).  That said I'm not sure if you are trying to create another Tab? or push another page onto the stack?

Comment: Where do you have navigationPane defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example for creating tabs for a different screen. You are in main tab to go next qml as follows:

```
Tab {
  title: "Puppies"
  NavigationPane {
    id: navigationPane
    Sample //this is one qml page as like Sample.qml
    {
    }
  }
}

Tab {
  title: "Kittens"
  NavigationPane
  {
    id: testpage
    Test //this is one qml page as like Test.qml
    {
    }
  }
}
```

You can access other QML files by setting the id.